# Show that $AA^{T}$ is symmetric and positive-definite

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, positive-definite

I am trying to show that if $A$ is a $2 \times 3$ matrix of rank $2$, then $AA^{T}$ is symmetric and positive-definite.

Showing that it's symmetric seems simple. Take $A = \left[\begin{array}{lll}
a & c & f \\
b & d & g
\end{array}\right]$. Then $AA^{T} = \left[\begin{array}{ll}
a^{2}+c^{2}+f^{2} & a b+c d+f g \\
a b+c d+f g & b^{2}+d^{2}+g^{2}
\end{array}\right]$, which is clearly symmetric.

However, this seems a bit long-winded. Is there a more general way to show this ? What is the usual interpretation of the matrix $AA^{T}$ ?

Now, to show that it's positive definite I understand that I need to show that $q(x) = x^{T}Ax \geq 0 \space \forall x$ and $q(x)=0 \iff x=\vec{0}$.

What is the best route to show this here ? Can I use the fact that the matrix has rank 2? Calcualting the eigenvalues, and determining if they're both positive, for general entries, also seems long-winded. I'm sure there a straight-forward way to show this.

Comment: For the first part, you could use the following property: ${}^t(ab)={}^{t}b\,{}^ta$.

Comment: For symmetry, you can use $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$ and $((A)^T)^T = A$

Answer (score 3):

A matrix $M$ is symmetric iff $M^T = M$. You can therefore prove the claim for *any* matrix $A$ as follows:
$$ (AA^T)^T = (A^T)^T(A)^T = AA^T $$
by using the transpose property that $(AB)^T = B^TA^T$. To show positive-definiteness, notice that
$$ u^T (AA^T) u = (A^T u)^T(A^Tu) = ||A^Tu||^2 \geq 0$$
for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Moreover, $\text{rank}(A)=2$ implies that $A^T : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is also of rank 2 (since column rank is equal to row rank), which in turn implies by the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem) that $A^T$ has trivial kernel, i.e. $A^Tu = 0$ implies $u = 0$. We conclude that $AA^T$ is positive-definite.

Comment: Perfect. But what exactly is the rank 2 doing in the argument for positive-definiteness ? Can you expand a bit ?

Comment: Yes! I've just added further explanation, feel free to ask anything that still isn't clear.